# Java service getting killed on linux. Need help to understand the behavior

Tags: java, jvm

I have one of the node in the cloud that has few java services running like logstash, newrelic collector etc. After few days i saw one of the service is dead. var/log/messages says following

> Nov 21 09:34:26 xxx-yyyy-services-18a kernel: Killed process 7912, UID
>   10112, (java) total-vm:3912228kB, anon-rss:867496kB, file-rss:268kB

After it was killed I looked at the total mem usage. I dont think this would help but just want to give how much memory currently it is using.

> > Memory config  free -mh
> >                  total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached Mem:          3.7G       3.3G       410M       144K        42M 
> >     392M
> >     -/+ buffers/cache:       2.9G       845M Swap:           0B         0B         0B

Java service are configured to use following xmx values

newRelic -Xms256m -Xmx1024m ( 2 instances)
logstash -Xmx500m
other java services :- all 5 services are configured with -Xms256m -Xmx1024m

So based on this configuration, total service are configured to use more memory that system has, which is fine as long as they are not consuming it. But I still need to understand what might have happened and how do I debug what has happened. all service are configured to dump the heap but I dont see the core file anywhere(though it wont happen since the system doesn't have mem to even dump the heap?) Trying to understand what has happened and what does the var/log/message means?

I came across this post which explains about process being killed.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128642/debug-out-of-memory-with-var-log-messages

can someone explain based on their experience what may have happened?

Comment: They are probably configured to dump the heap when they encounter a *Java* OOM, not a kernel OOM, in which the kernel just kills the process immediately. But really, this is not a programming question, you should try it on Superuser/Server fault.

Comment: You say "killed on Linux", does it run fine on any other OS? Just wondering if it is anything to do with "nohup"

Comment: I dont know about other OS, since we do it only on linux.

Comment: Yes do you know how does it decide which process to really kill when system goes out of memory? May be I will try other forums. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's the OOM killer killing a process since you're running out of memory.

Observe your memory usage to find out what's taking too much and adjust the amounts you're giving to your services. Or add more memory to your server.

Comment: note that "more memory" can also mean more swap, which is sufficient in some cases.

Comment: True, but you probably don't want the server that's running important services to be swapping.